# What do these different execution environments in Eclipse mean?

Tags: java, eclipse

What are the differences between these different Execution environments I'm seeing in Eclipse? It seems they're all under the same JDK version. I'm particularly interested in:

- What do they represent exactly?
- When will I choose one over the other? The J2SE ones are straightforward, but what are those CDC and OSGi for?

[image]

Comment: OSGi is a module layer and service layer for Java, entire Eclipse is based on OSGi. It is another way of building apps. Read more info here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Execution_Environments#What_are_Execution_Environments.3F) should answer your question:

> Execution environments (EEs) are symbolic representations of JREs. For
>   example, rather than talking about a specific JRE, with a specific
>   name at a specific location on your disk, you can talk about the
>   J2SE-1.4 execution environment. The system can then be configured to
>   use a specific JRE to implement that execution environment.
>   Execution environments are relevant both to development (compile) time and runtime.